# Máscara para Campo de Nota - 10 ou 5,5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou buscando um script em **jQuery** pra fazer uma máscara:

Quando tiver digiando `10`, o campo formatar para `10,0` e quando for outra nota como por exemplo `6,5` deixar assim.

Como exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que delimite no momento que for digitando e não depois que clicar fora do campo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

olha, vou postar uma sugestão, onde a mascara sempre tem uma casa decimal e permite apenas numeros entre 0 e 10.

```js
var notas = document.getElementsByClassName("nota"); 

var onNotaInput = function (event) {
  var regexp = new RegExp("[^0-9]", "g");
  var value = event.target.value.replace(regexp, "");
  value = parseInt(value) / 10;
  if (value >= event.target.min && value <= event.target.max) {
    event.target.dataset.value = value;
  } else {
    value = parseFloat(event.target.dataset.value);
  }
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    value = 0;
  }

  event.target.value = value.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 1 });
};

[].forEach.call(notas, function (nota) {
  nota.addEventListener("input", onNotaInput);
});
```

```html
<label>
  Nota 01:
  <input class="nota" type="text" min="0" max="10" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
  Nota 02:
  <input class="nota" type="text" min="0" max="10" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
  Nota 03:
  <input class="nota" type="text" min="0" max="10" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
  Nota 04:
  <input class="nota" type="text" min="0" max="10" />
</label>
```

Comment: Exatamente TobyMosque só uma duvida com ID pego só um input não é? como seria com vários inputs tentei colocar "document.getElementsByClassName" mas da erro "addEventListener"

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` retorna uma coleção, então você tem percorrer a mesma.

Comment: poderia me dizer como faz?

Comment: @ThallesDaniel, a resposta já está atualizada

Comment: Muito bom mesmo. Se adicionar o if que usei pra ignorar teclas de seta, backspace etc ficaria ainda melhor.

Comment: não há a necessidade, o evento `input` é disparado apenas quando o valor do input sofre alteração, desta forma ele não é disparado quando uma seta é utilizada, mas é disparado quando um valor é colado no input.

Answer (score 4):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer formatar o campo com uma casa decimal. Tente esse código:

```
$("#valor").on("change", function()
{
    this.value = Number(this.value.replace(",", ".")).toFixed(1).replace(".", ",");
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhg7t6a/1/)**</kbd>

**Atualização**

O mais próximo que consegui com masked input foi nisso:

```
$.mask.definitions['~']='([0-9] )?';
$("#valor").mask("~9,9", {placeholder: " "});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhg7t6a/3/)**</kbd>

<sup>Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15371303/1267304).</sup>

Porém a máscara ficou uma *osta e não consegui limitar o número até 10.

**Atualização 2**

Fazendo uma máscara na mão, específica para o seu caso, cheguei nesse código:

```
$("#valor").on("keyup", function(e)
{
    var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

    // do nothing if it's an arrow key or backspace
    if(code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40 || code == 8) {
        return;
    }

    var num = Number(this.value.replace(",", "."));

    if (this.value.replace(",", "").length > 2) num = num * 100;

    var value = (num <= 10 ? num : 10);

    this.value = value.toFixed(1).replace(".", ",");
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhg7t6a/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: eu preciso que seja como o Masked Input  no momento da digitação e não depois que clique fora :(

Comment: Acho que não tem sentido o que ele quer. Se eu digitar no campo `55`, ele quer que mostre `5,5`. Mas se eu digitar `10` para deixar `10`. Mas com a máscara ficará `1,0`. O certo nesse caso, pra mim, é apenas tratar o `.`(ponto) e deixar colocar `,` (vírgula) apenas. E o usuário que digite certo! Apenas verifique se a nota está acima de 10 ou menor que 10.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel então tem um limite ? De 0 a 10 ? Pra formatar em tempo real, apenas troque o evento para `keyup`, [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhg7t6a/2/), mas aí o campo necessita de outros tratamentos.

Comment: preciso que quando digite 10 fique "10,0" e quando digite 5,5 fique "5,5" no Masked Input  ele ja deixa limitado como vc escreve mas ele fica ou 10,0 e quando digito menor fica 05,0. Só queria apenas alterar pra qnd for 10 ou menor seria notas entenderam?   Nota do aluno 10,0 ou 5,6 exemplo

Comment: Ainda não entendi. Agora acho que você está pedindo o contrário do que pediu no começo. Acho que você deveria editar seu POST e escrever exatamente o que você precisa, com exemplos... Narre o que você quer. Tipo: **Exemplo 1** -  eu quero digitar no campo `10,0` e quero que apareça `10`. **Exemplo 2** - mas quando eu digitar `5,5` quero que fique assim. *Pelo menos foi isso o que eu entendi inicialmente.*.

Comment: @DiegoSouza é um campo input de nota de aluno. eu preciso que delimite no momento que a pessoa digita se ela digitar 10 o campo fique 10,0 e caso ela digite abaixo disso exemplo 8 ficaria assim mesmo 8,0 . E caso ela digite 5,7 uma valor real ficaria assim msm 5,7 entendeu mas eu preciso fazer isso no momento que digite como o maskedinput faz

Comment: @ThallesDaniel atualização.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel mais uma atualização.

Comment: Com 10 funciona, mas com nota tipo 8,5 não vai.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel eu consegui digitar `8,5`. Não é a máscara perfeita, mas quebra um galho. Melhor que isso só um código mais complexo.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel mas a máscara que postei do masked input parece que atende o formato do seu print.